# i can't set up a breakpoint and these lines of code don't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, breakpoints

i'm building my solution on release mode on vs2010, also it's a c++ code. All lines are working properly, but just 4 line don't work and i can't set up a breakpoint these lines. they are a if block. i rebuilt solution and check my pdb file but it doesn't work. Who can help to me?

Comment: build in debug mode instead of release mode

Comment: but in my test environment hasn't got debug libraries so i must built in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Release configuration doesn't contain symbols and is fully optimized (even if it created PDBs they don't contain the necessary information for a full debugging experience), which means that you cannot set breakpoints.

However, it is possible to build a Release version that includes debugging information from VS IDE - you can configure it in your project's settings. 
See [Project Settings for a C++ Debug Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kcw4dzyf.aspx) and [Enabling Debug Features in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bb575z2.aspx) 
I don't have VS2010 and I don't remember how the project settings are, but you should check something like: 
Linker setting where you need to check an option to generate debug info; 'C++' tab where you can specify what type of debug info to generate.